Trying to implement pub/sub but like instagram
I'm trying to do a thing where a user has a profile and when user creates a content all the people who follow the user get notified in their feed. How would I do this with websocket and redis?

However it is not expertise of the Redis, (you better use stacks such as Kafka or RabbitMQ, etc), you can make use of  PubSub commands (https://redis.io/docs/latest/develop/interact/pubsub/) and a http-websocket-compatible server (depend of programming language you use, for example gorilla for GoLang)
